# How to change the name of an application that appears in ALT+TAB?

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8.1

Okay first: I know there are good reasons (malware, script-kiddies, etc) why this shouldn't be possible.

But I dont have bad intents. I've found this awesome explorer *replacement* [Clover](http://ejie.me/) which actually just adds tab functionality to the default Windows Explorer.

But it bothers me, that the icon and title are changed. ("Clover" instead of "Explorer") I've already changed the icon and the assembly infos of Clover with resourcehacker following [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14370553/changing-the-icon-of-an-exe-file-in-windows-7) and *everything* I've found in the registry.

[image]

[image]

**(How) Is it possible to change the name of an application that appears in the task switcher (better known as** <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd>**)?**

Answer (score 0):

No, unless you change the name of the application itself. There are many 3rd party programs to change the appearance of Alt+Tab but they can only change how they look, now the title of the individual applications.

**[Alt Tab Tuner](http://www.askvg.com/alt-tab-tuner-freeware-to-tweak-and-customize-alttab-switcher-screen-in-windows-7-and-windows-8/)**

1. Change thumbnail size
2. Change horizontal spacing between thumbnails
3. Change vertical spacing between thumbnails
4. Thumbnail margins
5. Horizontal and vertical offset settings of small icons which are shown in bottom-right 
   corner of thumbnails
6. Title text offset settings
7. Width of focus border which is shown around thumbnails
8. Change number of rows and columns of thumbnails (Windows 7 only)
9. Customize screen transparency (Windows 7 only)
10. Add fade effect when switching to Desktop (Windows 7 only)
11. Enable Windows XP style classic "Alt+Tab" switcher screen

Comment: "No, unless you change the name of the application itself." That's what I did actually. What do you mean by "the name"

Comment: Changing the title of the program, eg the text shown on the top bar.